# Gridlines in pandoc markdown tables

Tags: html-table, markdown, pandoc

I have searched for but have not found any discussing on creating HTML tables in Pandoc markdown that show Gridlines between the cells.

Could this have been discussed using other keywords? I would think someone would have asked for such a thing.

I am using pipe tables create a pen and paper form to be filled out when when provisioning laptops for new users.   I typically have to build 2-5 computers at the same time. Having lines between the columns and rows would be better than crating them with a pen and straight edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Pandoc settings to include a CSS files that adds the style to your tables.